# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, angular

Inside a `directive` in `Angular` I did the following:

```
let input: HTMLElement = renderer.createElement('input');
renderer.appendChild(this.elem.nativeElement, input);
```

and when I try to get the value writen inside this input using:

```
console.log('value', input.value);
```

I get this error:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

Although we all now that to get value from input using javascript we do the following:

```
document.getElementById("searchTxt").value;
```

and `document.getElementById()` return either null or `HTMLElement` object:

> /**
>        * Returns a reference to the first object with the specified value of the ID or NAME attribute.
>        * @param elementId String that specifies the ID value. Case-insensitive.
>        */
>       getElementById(elementId: string): HTMLElement | null;

so why I get this error ?!!

Comment: Why would you create an input this way ? [This kind of issue](http://xyproblem.info/) is usually how you create bad practices : tell us what you are trying to achieve, we'll tell you what you can do to achieve it !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `HTMLInputElement` instead:

```
let input: HTMLInputElement= renderer.createElement('input');
```

The HTMLElement interface has no "value" property in it, so you get those .ts errors. The HTMLInputElement interface extends HTMLElement and has a "value" property.

Comment: Not sure this will resolve the issue (unless it is a Linting issue)

Comment: @trichetriche This should resolve, the `HTMLInputElement ` extends the `HTMLElement ` interface. The `HTMLElement ` interface has no `value` prop in it but `HTMLInputElement ` has.

Comment: But as said, it's only a linting issue : Javascript not typing the elements, it won't resolve the console error that the OP can have post-build (but I don't think he has, it should simply log `undefined`)

Comment: Sure we don't need to cast to `HTMLInputElement` like `renderer.createElement('input') as HTMLInputElement;`

Comment: @trichetriche I'm using typescript (with angular) that's why it's better to specify the type of variables, so I can use vscode's intellisense.

Comment: @SlimenTN next time consider stating that it is a linting error and not an actual JS error, this would save time ! for slow-minded people like me, it can be of great help :D

Comment: @trichetriche: *slow-minded* LOL! I am still thinking why would it log `undefined` even if he was able to create the build after the `ts` error. Shouldn't it log the `value` if it is compiled successfully, no matter what the type is?

Comment: depends, if you create a `span` element, this would return `undefined`, as the `span` doesn't hold any `value`. But for the case of an input, yeah, this should return `''` by default !

Comment: @trichetriche yeah my bad there XD

Comment: @trichetriche another thing it actually did throw an error in my angular project not linting error only

Comment: @SlimenTN but probably not the same error as the linter ! (cmd errors are linting errors, JS errors are the ones you see in the browser console)